# Python requests page not found

Tags: python, python-requests

**General:**

> Request URL: http://172.28.0.254/esi/912100/esi.cgi?page=globalsettings-index.xml&userIdent=1530588493&menu=%22DNS%22&replace=inline&SharedTmpSid=08153828&cacheAvoider=1550572875602
>
> Request Method: GET
>
> Status Code: 200 OK
>
> Remote Address: 172.28.0.254:80
>
> Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

**Request Header:**

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 172.28.0.254
Referer: http://172.28.0.254/esi/912100/esi.cgi?page=index.xml&sessionID=1530588493
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.81 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

**Query String:**

```
page: globalsettings-index.xml
userIdent: 1530588493
menu: "DNS"
replace: inline
SharedTmpSid: 08153828
cacheAvoider: 1550572875602
```

upon is the trace from chrome
and here below is a picture showing the trace:
[image: the trace]

I wrote a script to get a page to get the feedback content, the response code is `200`, but requests feedback text is `<H1>globalsettings-index.xml Not Found</H1>`

Below is my script:

```
def revise_Dns(id,shareid):
    url1="http://172.28.0.254/esi/912100/esi.cgi"
    payload={
        "page": "globalsettings-index.xml",
        "userIdent": id,
        "menu": "DNS",`enter code here`
        "replace": "inline",
        "SharedTmpSid": shareid,
        "cacheAvoider": str(int(round(time.time() * 1000)))
    }
    g=r.get(url1,params=payload,headers=header)
    print g.status_code
    print g.text
revise_Dns(id,shareid)
```

looking for who can help me on this topic, thanks!

Comment: Can you share the header in your script ?
I've had a similar issue and fixed it by adding a user Agent

Comment: Headers is :header={
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.81 Safari/537.36"
}   and i add the headers to session as --> r.headers.update({"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
    r.headers.update({"Referer": "http://172.28.0.254/esi/912100/esi.cgi?page=index.xml&sessionID={}".format(id)})
    r.headers.update({"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"})

Comment: if the response is xml, it might be compressed,
will you try with g.content ? 
if it gives you output, 
just use something like :

`
from xml.etree import ElementTree


tree = ElementTree.fromstring(g.content)`

Comment: yes, the response is XML, i tried print g.content, the output is the same as g.text, i have no any idea about it.......